# Is there a demo for Onsen2/Angular 1.5.x that works with Webpack/Browserify?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, onsen-ui

I have been trying to figure how to set this up properly, but no luck. Screen looks blank and no errors on browser console.

Sample Github demo:
https://github.com/oocoder/onsenui-wp-demo

Has anybody tried to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  I was able to resolve the issue by assigning ons to the global window object and waiting for Angular on ready event to run the onsenui bindings.

Use: onsenui@2.0.0-beta.7

Sample: https://github.com/oocoder/onsenui-wp-demo

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with webpack, but adding Onsen to a project is really nothing more than adding some additional files to a standard html project.  Some installer options are listed here: https://onsen.io/guide/getting_started.html

Also, to get started with browserify, see the docs here: https://onsen.io/2/

```
var onsen = require('onsenui/js/onsenui');

onsen.ready(function() {
  onsen.notification.alert({message: 'Onsen UI works with browserify!'});
});
```

So, if that is not working, I often recommend for people to get started by going here:  https://monaca.io/cloud.html

Sign up for their free account which is to access their awesome cloud IDE.  From there, just create a project and select the Onsen 2.0 Quickstart.  After that you can export the project and import it into your favorite IDE.  You are now setup to develop Onsen apps.

On a side note, I really recommend their cloud IDE.  It has so many amazing features and it makes development a breeze.